# How to combine plot of two GPy models?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gpy, gpyopt

I have calculated two GP regression models and would like to have them plotted in the same figure.

**Model 1**

```
kernel = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=.1, lengthscale=1.)
m1 = GPy.models.GPRegression(xa, ya,kernel)
m1.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 10)
m1.optimize(messages=True)

from IPython.display import display
display(m1)

fig1 = m1.plot(plot_density=True) 
m1.plot(plot_density=True)
GPy.plotting.show(fig2, filename='2')
```

**Model 2**

```
m2 = GPy.models.GPRegression(xe, ye,kernel)
m2.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 10)
m2.optimize(messages=True)

from IPython.display import display
display(m2)

fig2 = m2.plot(plot_density=True,)

GPy.plotting.show(fig2, filename='2')
```

I want both plots in one figure, in either matplotlib or plotly i.e. `GPy.plotting.show(fig, filename='filename')`.

Thanks

Comment: This was surprisingly less-trivial than I originally thought it'd be. Documentation across GPy seems to be under continuous construction, and it took awhile to ascertain that GPy models are integrated with the matplotlib interface.

Answer (score 1):

Using `matplotlib`, you can define a subplot, and specify the subplot to be used using the same axes (specifically, param `ax`).

```
import matplotlib.plt as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
m1.plot(plot_density=True, ax=ax)
m2.plot(plot_density=True, ax=ax)
```

I tested this out with a test data set:

```
# Random Test Data
import pods
data = pods.datasets.olympic_marathon_men()

# First X,Y Regression Model
kernel = GPy.kern.RBF(input_dim=1, variance=.1, lengthscale=1.)
m1 = GPy.models.GPRegression(data['X'], data['Y'], kernel)
m1.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 10)
m1.optimize(messages=True)

# Second model; changed the X, Y slightly.
m2 = GPy.models.GPRegression(data['X'] + 5, data['Y'] + 3,kernel)
m2.optimize_restarts(num_restarts = 10)
m2.optimize(messages=True)
```

Related:
[What is the best way of combining two independent plots with matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204644/what-is-the-best-way-of-combining-two-independent-plots-with-matplotlib)

[image: Plot of two densities w/data]